# MYSQL: Get multiple-day event by date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

I am hoping someone can help me with this. I have an Events table that looks something like this:

```
title   | start_date          | end_date
---------------------------------------------------
Event 1 | 2020-09-01 13:00:00 | 2020-09-01 17:30:00
Event 2 | 2020-09-02 20:00:00 | 2020-09-02 21:00:00
Event 3 | 2020-09-01 07:00:00 | 2020-09-05 18:30:00
```

Now I would like to have a query that can return the events happening on a particular day.

For example:

`getEvents('2020-09-01 00:00:00');` would return **Event 1** and **Event 3**.

`getEvents('2020-09-02 00:00:00');` would return **Event 2** and **Event 3**.

`getEvents('2020-09-04 00:00:00');` would return **Event 3**.

What would be the ideal query to achieve this functionality? The main trouble I am facing at the moment is trying to validate the input date with multi-day events.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want rows that overlap with the search date.

Say you want events for September 1st, you would go:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.end_date >= '2020-09-01' and t.start_date < '2020-09-02'
```

Maybe you are going to pass the search date as a parameter:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.end_date >= ? and t.start_date < ? + interval 1 day
```